# Как оптимизировать запрос MySQL?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, выборка, select, запрос

Есть таблица `users`. В ней 500 000 пользователей. Нужно оптимизировать запрос выборки пользователей с учетом сортировки по `first_name`, `last_name` и т.д.

Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT
  `user_id`,
  `first_name`,
  `last_name`,
  `city_name`,
  `password`,
  `post_index`,
  `birthdate`,
  `salary`
FROM
  `users`
ORDER BY
  last_name ASC
LIMIT 0, 300
```

Но проблема в том, что выполняется он 1 минуту и 8 секунд на моем компьютере.

Подскажите, что можно сделать.

Comment: индексы к этим полям добавил?

Comment: для этого запроса достаточно индекса по last_name.

Comment: Добавил индекс вот так 

CREATE INDEX index_first_name ON users (first_name(26));

Но это не помогло.

Comment: @xdoctordog. У вас сортировка идет по last_name зачем вам индекс по first_name? он не будет использоваться. для этого запроса достаточно индекса по **last_name**.

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать:

1. Добавить индексы для `first_name, last_name`
2. Сделать составной индекс (`user_id, first_name, last_name, city_name, password, post_index, birthdate, salary`), будет покрывающим. Смешно для такого кол-ва полей
3. Добавляем составной индекс `uid_lname(user_id, last_name)` и разбиваем запрос на 2 запроса:

   - `SELECT user_id FROM users USE INDEX(uid_lname) ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 0, 300` - в этом случае индекс будет покрывающим и будет использоваться для сортировки
   - S`ELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, city_name, password, post_index, birthdate, salary FROM users WHERE user_id IN`(результат 1-го запроса)

Comment: Не помогло.
Добавил индекс вот так: 

CREATE INDEX index_first_name ON users (first_name(26));

И выполняю такой запрос

SELECT user_id,first_name,last_name,city_name,`password`,post_index,birthdate,salary FROM users USE INDEX (index_first_name) ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 0, 300

И он выполняется приблизительно то же время что и без индексов.

Comment: Пробую такую комбинацию 

CREATE INDEX index_uid_first_name ON users (user_id, first_name(10));

SELECT user_id,first_name,last_name,city_name,`password`,post_index,birthdate,salary FROM users USE INDEX (index_uid_first_name) ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 0, 300

Результат тот же.

Comment: В чем смысл создавать индекс по части колонки? Что говорит EXPLAIN?

Comment: ...а также не по тому полю.

Comment: first_name(26) - 26 это максимальная длина записи в поле?
 
В 1 случае можно без use index. Странно, что индекс по first_name не ускорил запрос. Сделай explain.
Во 2 случае у тебя запрос просто не будет использовать индекс.

Answer (score 1):

Если данные в таблице меняются не сильно часто то можно заранее отсортировать данные по нужному полю

```
ALTER TABLE users ORDER BY last_name ASC;
```

В этом случае  в селекте ORDER BY уже не нужен. Но для актуальности сортировки этот запрос нужно выполнять регулярно, например по крону раз в сутки.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не ворочать все данные разом, выберите сначала `id` и `lastname`. Отсортируйте по `lastname`, а остальные данные - присоедините через `JOIN` по `id`. Должно быть сильно быстрее.